# Flowable to perform task and return value using RxJava ReactiveX

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, micronaut, reactivex

I have the below method where I am checking if the file format is correct or not, if they are correct it adds to the `requestBody`, otherwise, it should throw an error message to the client that file format is not valid.

```
public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> images) {
        return Flowable.fromPublisher(images)
                .collect(MultipartBody::builder, (requestBody, file) -> {
                    if (new FileExtension().fileExtensionValidation(file.getFilename())) {
                        requestBody
                                .addPart("images", file.getFilename(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE, file.getBytes());
                    }
                })
                .flatMapMaybe(requestBody -> {
                    if (true)
                        return iImageUploadClient.post(requestBody.build());
                    else
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError("Image file extension invalid, should ne .png, .jpg, .jpeg,.gif"));
                });
    }
```

This code check the file format `if (new FileExtension().fileExtensionValidation(file.getFilename()))` when this fails to should return an message as `return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError("Image file extension invalid, should ne .png, .jpg, .jpeg,.gif"));`

I have written `if (true)` which is always correct, instead I need to check here or how can I return from `.collect()` function. How can I do this with reactive java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a shared AtomicBoolean between the collect and the last `flatMapMaybe`. In addition, if you want to stop the images right there, throw an exception and turn it into a neutral multipartbody so that `flatMapMaybe` still runs.

```java
public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> images) {
    return Maybe.<HttpResponse<?>>defer(() -> {
        AtomicBoolean formatError = new AtomicBoolean();
        return Flowable.fromPublisher(images)
                .collect(MultipartBody::builder, (requestBody, file) -> {
                    if (new FileExtension().fileExtensionValidation(file.getFilename())) {
                        requestBody
                                .addPart("images", file.getFilename(),
                                     MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE, file.getBytes());
                    } else {
                        formatError.set(true);
                        throw new CancellationException();
                    }
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
                     if (error instanceof CancellationException) {
                         return Single.just(MultipartBody.builder());
                     }
                     return Single.error(error);
                })
                .flatMapMaybe(requestBody -> {
                    if (!formatError.get())
                        return iImageUploadClient.post(requestBody.build());
                    else
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError(
                            "Image file extension invalid, should ne .png, .jpg, .jpeg,.gif"));
                });
    });
}
```

Comment: The return type is not matched. Getting an error as required maybe but found Flowable and return MultipartBody.builder(); is invalid return type

Comment: Right, you have `Maybe`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Also the return type is not correct for return MultipartBody.builder(); --> Bad return type in lambda expression: Builder cannot be converted to SingleSource<? extends Builder>

Comment: Yep, needs to be wrapped into a Single.